# RadioButton in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, detailsview

Sorry for my idiot question but i am newbie.
 - I have problem with my first time i use radiobutton. I want to make radiobutton like image below: 
[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2N3r.png)

- When radio button checked and i click on button this will open new page with details base on Gia(20$, 70$). But i don't know what to do.
- Index:

```html
@model List<Model.Select_buyVip_Result>

<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    <table style="width:50%" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Hình thức</th>
                <th>Giá</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" value="@item.Gia" /></td>
                    <td>@item.Ten</td>
                    <td>@item.Gia $</td>    
                </tr>
                @Html.ActionLink("Thanh toán", "Details", new { id=item.Gia})
            }
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

- Details:

```html
@model List<Model.Select_buyVip_byGia_Result>

<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    <table style="width:50%" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hình thức</th>
                <th>Giá</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Ten</td>
                    <td>@item.Gia $</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

- Controller:

```html
 public class MuaVipController : Controller
    {
        // GET: MuaVip
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var mm = new MuaVipModel();
            var model = mm.select_vip();
            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult Details(string gia)
        {
            var mm = new MuaVipModel();
            var model = mm.select_vip_gia(gia);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

- SQL procedure:

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE Select_buyVip_byGia 
 @Gia nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
 SELECT * from Vip where Gia = @Gia
END
GO
```

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE Select_buyVip 
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
 SELECT * from Vip 
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem !

Comment: i want use radiobutton and when i checked and click button this will get value Giá(Cost , ex:20$,70$) and open new details page by Gia. but i don't know what to do.

Comment: i know this is idiot question...

Comment: Your Radio button is already there and Details button is already there. What more do you need? the validations?

Comment: @Wiliam Which button are you referring to here? Any specific need for the radio button?

Comment: How can i get value of radio button that i checked? and put into Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered with simple JavaScript. When you check a radio button, the function (activated by the input button) checks if the radio is selected, and then moves you to a seperate page (item1_details.html or item2_details.html), where you can include the details about your item.

```js
function validate() {
  var item1 = document.getElementById("item1").checked;
  var item2 = document.getElementById("item2").checked;

  if (item1 == true) {
    location.href = "item1_details.html"
  }

  if (item2 == true) {
    location.href = "item2_details.html"
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td width="15%">
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" id="item1" name="optradio"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>Item 1</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>9.99</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" id="item2" name="optradio"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>Item 1</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>10.99</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Submit">
</center>
```

Or, you could open a modal based on what item you selected:

```js
 function validate() {
  var item1 = document.getElementById("item1").checked;
  var item2 = document.getElementById("item2").checked;
  
  if (item1 == true) {
   location.href = "#openModal1"
  }
  
  if (item2 == true) {
   location.href = "#openModal2"
  }
 }
```

```css
.modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #eee;
    }

    .closeModal {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  border: none;
  height: 24px;
    }

    .closeModal:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td width="15%">
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" id="item1" name="optradio"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>Item 1</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>9.99</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" id="item2" name="optradio"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>Item 1</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="radiotext">
            <label>10.99</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<center>
 <input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Submit">
</center>
<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <button onclick="location.href = '#close'" title="Close" class="closeModal">&times;</button>
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <p>Use this space to describe your first item.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <button onclick="location.href = '#close'" title="Close" class="closeModal">&times;</button>
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <p>Use this space to describe your second item.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

(View original modal code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vykc/))